# Are "expecting" and "expected" different?

Tags: grammar, word-difference

Is there a difference when using "expected" and "expecting" in this sentence?

> By 2025 it is **expected** that consumption will reach 140 units.
>   By 2025 it is **expecting** that consumption will reach 140 units.

Comment: The first is correct. The second is wrong.**Expecting** doesn't work after **it** unless **it** refers to some pregnant animal - which is unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

The first one is correct whereas the second one makes no sense.

That consumption will reach 140 units **can be** expected but **can't be expecting.**

It is a passive voice and there should not be an active verb there.

You can expect that consumption will reach 140 units.

or

It can be expected that consumption will reach 140 units.